# check multiple input fields with one variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot input boxes and I need to make a condition that checks if all of them are empty how can I do this in javascript with a single variable. This is what I have, but it only checks 1 box

```
function boxes() {

    var box_a = document.getElementById('box_a');

         if(box_a==="")   {
            alert("box not filled")
               return false;
          } 

 <input type="text" id="box_a">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*with a single variable*"? If taken literally, it's hardly possible

Comment: Please tell us which boxes you have. Currently all the boxes you showed to us are handled by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var textinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

var empty = [].filter.call( textinputs, function( el ) {
   return !el.value
});

if ( textinputs.length == empty.length ) {
  // all text inputs are empty
}
```

Comment: I think OP mentioned as textbox and in plain JS

Comment: Oh right, for some reason I read checkboxes. Modified. It is plain JS tho.

Comment: used the code and it's all working great, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean all of the inputs on the page, you can use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
function boxes() {
    var anyFilled = false;

    var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if(boxes[i].value !== "") {
            anyFilled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(anyFilled)
        alert('An input has a value');
}
```

Comment: Good to know. If both answers solves your question, choose one and mark as accepted answer.